# RequestModel is null when enum is wrong

Tags: c#, .net-core, enums, modelstate

If you have this enum :

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2
}
```

And this Request :

```
{
   "myEnum" : "WrongValue",
   "name" : "MyName"
}
```

In the controller :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RequestAsync(
        [FromBody] MyRequest myRequest)
    {
    }
```

myRequest is null.

But if you use ;

```
{
   "myEnum" : "Value1",
   "name" : "MyName"
}
```

It is not null.

Comment: Try making your `myEnum` property `nullable` using `?`